# Compute the volume of this object

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, volume

> The object $B\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by $x^2+y^2\leq1$ and
>   $0\leq z\leq x^2+y^2$. Compute $vol(B)$

My work:

I switched to cylindrical coordinates. so now the equations we get are:

$0\leq r\leq 1\ and\  0\leq z\leq r^2$

So $vol(B)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{r^2}rdzdrd\theta=2\pi\int_0^1r^3dr=2\pi/4=\pi/2$. Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes you are correct.